# Windows Server 2012R2 / Windows 8.1 - Layout stuck

Tags: windows-8, keyboard-layout, windows-server-2012, input-languages

I have experienced this **random** **problem** both on Windows 8.1 Pro and the Server 2012R2 I use now.
**Basically, you cannot change layout for some reason.**

- I have two layouts. US/HUN. One layout/language.
- I have tried switching via the taskbar, it won't do anything that way.
  It shows "HUN" if I click on the button in the taskbar, but without clicking, it shows US. And it works like a US layout, does not matter what it shows. Like it's stuck.
- ALT-SHIFT won't work. Changing that to a new hotkey won't work either.

What did I do before this happened? Nothing.
I left the computer here, came back, and had no layout switching. Again, the Win8.1 install had the issue

**Only way to fix it? Reboot.** That's right, in 2014, fixing Windows. One reboot at a time.
Again, if you have a bad luck (well, I do), the layout will be stuck in no time.

**Additional informations:**
The two machines are different so I don't think it's an application.
Heck, the Server is a brand new installation. Both are up-to-date. Every update is installed.

Of course I'm willing to provide any additional information you ask for.
The current Server 2012R2 app list:

[image]

**Update #1**

- Interestingly enough, I found a way to fix the issue. Well, "fix".
  http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/desktop/change-language-in-windows-8-metro/cf2c5f21-f90e-4fdc-a327-a2412af32142

  The **up/down** part is the key. HOWEVER, this is by no means a "fix". Just a dirty workaround.

Comment: I guess when the problem occurs the Win+Space shortcut to switch layouts doesn't work either?

Comment: Indeed. it's dead.

Comment: If you are able to reproduce the issue all the time, you could try a [clean boot](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135/en-us) (in case you haven't already).

Comment: @and31415: A simple "reboot" (not the full one) works. So really, it's a mistery. Of course I will try to track this down, because it's *really* annoying.